# Not able to Update the LINQ list

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have a list of Products that came from the database and from this list, I used LINQ and return as a List of Phone class.

```
List<Product> products = new List<Product>
{
   new Product { ID = 1, Name = "Alcohol", Expired = false },
   new Product { ID = 2, Name = "Phone", Expired = false },
   new Product { ID = 2, Name = "Phone", Expired = false },
   new Product { ID = 3, Name = "Computer", Expired = false },
   new Product { ID = 4, Name = "Chair", Expired = false },

 };


 var results = from i in products.Where(o => o.Name == "Phone")
               select new Phones
               {
                  ID = i.ID,
                  Phone = i.Name,
                  isChild = i.Expired
               };
 //Update the isChild property
 foreach (var item in results)
 {
    item.isChild = true;
 }

public class Phones
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    public bool isChild { get; set; }
}
```

I used to update the list of Phones using foreach loop. But the problem is when I checked the results variable it doesn't update the said items.

Comment: Show the class Phones and Product in your question code, it will make it a lot easier to paste into a test harness.

Comment: The Phone and Product has the same DataType.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thats because of deferred execution of the IEnumerable. Try casting your results ToList to immediate execute that query:

```
 var results = (from i in products.Where(o => o.Name == "Phone")
           select new Phones
           {
              ID = i.ID,
              Phone = i.Name,
              isChild = i.Expired
           }).ToList();
```

If you won't - it would requery the products every time and you will work with a new set of Phones.